# "Global" version of a classical elementary lemma in viscosity solutions theory on sequence of "local" strict maximum (minimum) points

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

**Lemma 2.4** at **page 8** of [these lecture notes on viscosity solutions theory](https://www.math.psu.edu/bressan/PSPDF/hj.pdf) is a classical and frequently used result.

Does the lemma (and its proof) hold true if we replace **"local"** with **"global"** throughout?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

Yes: If $\Omega$ is compact, you just need to change $|x-y|=\rho$ to $|x-y|\geqslant\rho$ in lines 3 and 5 of the proof.

No: Take $u(x)=-\cos(x)$ and $\phi(x)=0$ on $\Omega=(-2\pi,2\pi)$. Then $u$ has a strict global minimum on $\Omega$ at $0$, but $u_n(x)=-\cos(x)-x^2/n$ has no global minimum on $\Omega$.

(And $u_n(x)=-\cos(x)-x^{2n}(4\pi^2-x^2)$ does have a global minimum on $\Omega$ somewhere near $\pm 2\pi$).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. About the yes part: what role does the compactness condition play? About the no part: I don't  understand why it is a counterexample?

Comment: Compactness is needed to conclude that if $u(y)>u(x)$ for all $y$ such that $|y-x|\geqslant\rho$, then $u(y)>u(x)+\epsilon_\rho$ for these $y$. This is no different from Bressan's notes, where compactness of the sphere $|y-x|=\rho$ is used. I am not sure if there is anything I could add about the counterexample: $u$, $u_n$ and $\phi$ simply do not satisfy the assertion of the lemma (with every occurrence of "local" replaced by "global"). Or maybe I did not understand correctly your question?

Comment: If $x $ is a global minimum doesn't $u(y)>u (x)$ for all $y$? Where is compactness needed? (also, in the original  proof?)

Comment: In the counterexample, the statement seems to be false even in the local case. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your answer. Before I award the bounty, would you mind addressing the comments from the OP?

Comment: @Dal: Whoops, I overlooked these comments, sorry.

Comment: @Rene: (1) Yes, $u(y) > y(x)$ for all $y \ne x$, but in order to sharpen this to $u(y) > u(x) + \varepsilon$ we need a compact set of points $y$: this is why we restrict our attention to $|y - x| \geqslant \rho$. (2) We use compactness to get the improved inequality in the following way: $u(y) - u(x)$ is a positive continuous function of $y$, defined on a compact set $|y - x| \geqslant \rho$. Thus, it attains a (positive) minimal value $m$; that is, $u(y) - u(x) \geqslant m$. Take $\varepsilon=m/2$ to get a sharp inequality. (3) No, the local case is fine: $u_n(0)$ is a local minimum of $u_n$.